# Нужны ли сообществу метки «пушкин» и «л-толстой»?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

[Пунктуация в предложении Л. Толстого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458870/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9B-%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)
[Обособление обстоятельства, выраженного одиночным деепричастием](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458988/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)
[«Тогда бы он дурно поступил(,) и я бы не жалела его»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458869/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)
[«Не любивший противоречий(,) и в особенности таких»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460208/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85)
[«…и(,) когда он приехал на покос, косцы шли уже по второму ряду»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460015/%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83)
[«…Каренина(,) в придворном мундире с новою красною лентою через плечо»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461030/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE) (сегодня)

Вот **несколько** вопросов (что вспомнились), в которых была использована метка «л-толстой». В одном из них (в каком именно — не могу сказать, так как комментарии уничтожены [***почему*** их нужно изничтожать?!]), но не в последнем, между мной и модератором случился спор.

Я сделала правку вопроса и добавила в него метку «л-толстой» (уже несколько раз до этого используемую). Модератор ее удалил. После удаления метки я спросила *Aer♦* — почему?
Он ответил, что считает использование этой метки нецелесообразным, что так можно всех писателей «понаперечислить».
Я возразила, потому что ориентировалась на метку «пушкин» (помнится, что *Александр Стрелец* меня поддержал).
Мне дали ответ: нужно и Пушкина удалить; я принял решение, не согласны — задайте вопрос на Мете.

Не согласна. Задаю.
Теперь вместо метки «л-толстой» красуется целесообразная «недопустимая метка».
Вот [*страница с меткой «пушкин»*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags?page=7&tab=popular): множество нечасто используемых меток (с количеством шесть или семь заданных по ним вопросов) — и никто их не «выключает».

Так сообразно или нет?

Comment: Мне очень грустно из-за того, что вы делаете из меня диктатора: «Я принял решение...» Я такого не писал. Было лишь: «Пушкин и все подобные я бы удалил: слишком много будет бесполезных меток. Тютчев, Фет, Некрасов, Черубина де Габриак, Чёрный... подтянутся. Вы можете инициировать обсуждение на Мете, конечно же. Свое мнение я высказал».

Comment: _Мне очень грустно из-за того, что вы делаете из меня диктатора..._ Ведь так и есть! Вы же не дождались вопроса-обсуждения на Мете — а метка уже уничтожена. P. S. Я, конечно же, не смогла привести Ваши высказывания дословно (потому что, повторю, комментарии к вопросу уничтожены), но смысл, мне кажется, однозначен: мнение высказал... И принял решение. P. P. S. О чём Вы — Пупкин — Васильков — Пушков? Два автора, два **классика** всего в метках (возможно, кому-то глобально интересны)...

Comment: Комментарии никем не уничтожены, будьте внимательней. У меня не было возможности инициировать обсуждение, поэтому я поступил в соответствии с текстом Справки: «В целом, по возможности, рекомендуется избегать создания новых меток, а новые пользователи не могут создавать новые метки». Вы инициировали обсуждение — и, если будет какой-либо консенсус между участниками, конечно, результаты будут учтены. Интересные у вас представления о диктатуре!

Comment: Я категорически не согласен с вашим подходом «кому-то интересны». Мне вот интересен стиль работ В. В. Виноградова. Теперь метку создавать? Он классик науки...

Answer (score 1):

Аргументы против:

1. Сайт не посвящен изучению авторского стиля кого бы то ни было: это область литературоведения.
2. Кто будет решать, когда метка [пупкин](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bd) допустима, а когда — нет? Если я спрошу про книгу Натальи О'Шей, мне создавать метку [ошей](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b9)? И так с каждым автором? От этого мало пользы, а вреда больше: слишком много меток — плохо.
3. Как правило, вопросы о пунктуации в тексте того или иного автора не связаны с этим самым автором. Вопрос должен снабжаться меткой [редактор-васильков](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) или [корректор-пушков](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2), но не, например, [а-блок](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba), у которого с запятыми было не очень (с современной точки зрения, конечно же).

Comment: @Аer, поддерживаю ваше решение. Смысла нет. Зачем создавать новые метки, когда существует метка "Пунктуация".